# Creating and Removing an Map from HazelCast

Tags: hazelcast

I am using the following code to create an map in HazelCast

```
HazelcastInstance instance = null;
Config cfg = new Config();
instance =Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
instance.getMap(mapName);
```

Once I am done with the my processing I want to remove this map from HazelCast. Can you Please suggest how to go about it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I did not receive any replies but got the answer. You can use

```
instance.getMap(mapName).destroy();
```

I am posting this so that it might help someone else in need.